# Is there a way to get the struct input_dev for a character device driver given the /dev/input/eventX file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In kernel context, is there a way to use the kernel's file system/input-core API to grab the corresponding device driver struct input_dev (include/linux/input.h) given only a character file descriptor for an input event (/dev/input/eventX)?